# How to manipulate size and position of image inside a digital signature rectangle? Itextsharp

Tags: itext

I need to simultaneously stamp both a string (details of the user) and an image containing an actual signature in a pdfDocument. The string and image are successfully stamped on the document, however, the image of the actual signature is being stretched to fit the rectangle of the whole signature. how do i fix this and manipulate the size and position of the image?

I used both Layer2Text and Image function in one stamper declaration. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Instead of merely setting the `Layer2Text` and `Image` and letting iTextSharp arrange everything, you can create the signature appearance all by yourself on the `PdfTemplate` returned by  `GetLayer(2)`.

If you need some inspiration on how to fill that layer, you can look at the [PdfSignatureAppearance.cs](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfSignatureAppearance.cs) method `GetAppearance()`, more exactly the section between

```
if (app[2] == null) {
```

and

```
}
if (app[3] == null && !acro6Layers) {
```

This is where iTextSharp creates the default appearance on the `PdfTemplate t`. Your code may vary only slightly.